# customize wordpress database error page

Tags: php, customization, plugin-w3-total-cache, cache, errors

**UPDATE**

Initially I suspected this was related to the Wordpress framework I'm using (Genesis) or to my child theme functionality, but turns out that's not the case as I was able to get this to work in a test environment running on the same framework and child theme.

Possibly this is related to the caching plugin I'm using, W3 Total Cache. If this plugin is not active, then the custom db-error.php file is picked up.

To rephrase my question, has anyone run into this issue with caching plugins being active?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Has anyone successfully been able to replace the default Wordpress database error page with a custom one?

I tried this (add db-error.php under wp-content), but I can't get it to work for some reason:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/custom-database-error-page/

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me as `db-error.php` in wp-content:

*Delete the mailer block if you don't want it*

```
<?php header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'); ?>

<?php 
$to = "me@mysite.com"; 
$subject = "My Database is down"; 
$message = "My Database is down"; 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n"; 
$headers .= "From: \"Admin\" <me@mysite.com>\n"; 
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
?> 


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            h1, p {
                font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 26px;
                color: #333;
                }
            p {
                font-size: 16px;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


   <center>
            <h1>My Site is taking a nap right now....</h1>
        <p>But really, we're currently experiencing technical issues &mdash; Please check back soon....</p>
   </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: still getting the default WP one. I wonder if it's related to the way I'm triggering the db connection error page (by entering wrong db info in wp-config)?

Comment: Looks like it's related to the caching plugin I'm using, updated my question. Will post more here as I troubleshoot this some more.

Comment: Then disallow that file to be cached in W3TC.

Answer (score 0):

This is still the case in 4.2.2.  If DB_NAME or DB_USER is wrong, you get the nice "Can't select database" screen from wp-db.php.  If DB_PASSWORD or DB_HOST is wrong, db-error.php gets called.  Weird.

Without db-error.php, the nice screen gets rendered for all four of the above errors, which is a more consistent user experience (just no webmaster email).